# Material UI Autocomplete onInputChange() called twice when component is first mounted and input is given

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui, safari

My Material UI Autocomplete component looks like this:

```
<Autocomplete
      open={!!value || !!inputValue}
      getOptionLabel={(option) =>
        typeof option === "string" ? option : option.suggestion
      }
      filterOptions={(x) => x}
      forcePopupIcon={false}
      options={options}
      autoComplete
      filterSelectedOptions
      value={value}
      onChange={(event: any, newValue: Suggestion | null) => {
        setOptions(newValue ? [newValue, ...options] : options);
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        console.log("onInputChange()");
        setInputValue(newInputValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          fullWidth
          label={!!value || !!inputValue ? "" : "Search a location"}
          focused
          autoFocus
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
        />
      )}
      renderOption=<render-options>
    />
```

I noticed that when the component is first loaded and an input is given, `onInputChange()` is being called twice on Chrome & Firefox. It is called only once in Safari. I was wondering why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using StrictMode?

Comment: I haven't explicitly enabled it but I'm using next.js 14.0.0. This link https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode
suggests that StrictMode is enabled by default post next.js 13.4

Comment: When StrictMode is enabled the component render twice in development mode, this helps catching bugs. try to disable it or run a build of your app and see if it still happens